# Refreshing a binded property from another Thread doesn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin

In a Xamarin project, I am trying to update a label showed in a loading page.
The loading page contains also an activity indicator control and is showed after the user clicks *OK* on a display alert and the alert is showed after the user clicks on a button in the UI.

The loading page is necessary because some heavy activity happens in background. Every seconds I query the status of the activity and I want this status be showed on a loading page, giving the user some information about the activity. This activity is wrappred in a *ICommand* in the ViewModel.

When I run the command I want a variable in the viewModel referred by the page be updated.
The command is executed in a Task.Run method otherwise the loading page is not showed untill the command has done.

This is the code:

#### **View code behind**

```
private async void SelfLearningButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bindingContext = BindingContext as AutomationViewModel;
        if (await DisplayAlert("message",
                              "OK", "Cancel"))
        {
            bindingContext.IsLearning = true; //a variable that drives the ISVisibleProperty of the loading page
            //Task.Run because the loading page must be showed otherwise I wait for the command to be completed (with async/await too)
            _ = Task.Run(() => bindingContext.TheCommand.Execute(null));
        }
    }
```

#### **View.xaml**

```
<Label IsVisible="{Binding IsLearning}"
                       TextColor="#f1c00e"
                       Padding="0, 20, 0, 0"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       x:Name="LearningStatus"
                       Text="{Binding Status}">
```

#### **View Model**

```
//The variable that must be updated
public string Status
    {
        private set
        {
            if (_status != value)
            {
                _status  = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get { return _status ; }
    }

TheCommand= new Command( 
          async () =>
            {
                try
                {

                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < 10000 )
                    {
                        ++i;
                        //Doesn't work
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( ()=> _status= i.ToString()); //sorry for the boxing
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //
                }
                finally
                {
                    IsLearning = false;
                }
         });
```

When I run the code of the command the *BeginInvokeOnMainThread* doesn't update the variable. I use BeginInvokeOnMainThread because view items must be updated in the UI thread. At every iteration *_status* has the same value used for init it,  and setter code of the field is not called. What is going wrong with this code?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't you set `Status` instead of `_status` since `NotifyPropertyChanged` won't be called?

Comment: `_status= i.ToString()` is updating the internal backing store, not the public property

Comment: @Luke Vo, I tried but nothing happens.

Comment: @zappasan I can't remember if the default mode is OneTime. Try setting the [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode) to `OneWay`? Also how is `NotifyPropertyChanged` implemented? I thought you have to specify the property name? And a note, if you are using model binding, you don't need `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.

Comment: Ok guys, my fault, I made a number of proofs, but I didn't try to put the property inside the BeginInvokeOnMainThread method. My fault! I apologize. Now it works